# Creating a new float (memoir)

Tags: floats, memoir

I recently started using `memoir`. Previously I had a number of floats defined using `float` package-- `attachment`, `code`, and `illustration` in addition to default `figure` and `table`.

Now that I'm trying to define new floats in `memoir` way, I'm struggling a bit. I followed `memoir` documentation and defined `illustration` as below:

```
\newcommand{\illustrationname}{Illustration}
\newfloat[chapter]{illustration}{lol}{\illustrationname}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
\begin{illustration}
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{2027-original}
 \illustrationname{caption goes here}
 \label{ill:2027}
\end{illustration}
```

However, when I run pdflatex, I get the following error:

```
<use ./images/2027-original.png> [5 <./images/2027-original.png>] [6]
! Use of \pictur@ doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \includegraphics
```

So how can I make this illustration float to use `\includegraphics`?

Comment: You should use `\caption{...}`, not `\illustrationname{...}` for you illustration caption. Regardless, a minimal example using the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) - note the `x` - works without problem. Are you perhaps using the [`graphics` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphics)?

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me:

In the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\illustrationname}{Illustration}
\newfloat[chapter]{illustration}{lol}{\illustrationname}
```

In the body:

```
\begin{illustration}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{2027-original}
 \caption{caption goes here}
 \label{ill:2027}
\end{illustration}
```

Comment: Is the above fragment complete and sufficient? Did you separately need to define a counter and an environment? I am trying to do the same thing as you and using section 10.1 of the `memoir` manual but am having a hard time! Thanks.